# Why I would use ".format()" instead of "+"?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I was wondering why I should use something like this:

```
name = "Doe"
surname = "John"
print("He is {0} {1}".format(surname, name))
```

Instead of:

```
name = "Doe"
surname = "John"
print("He is" + surname + " " + name)
```

Comment: More readable and more pythonic. :)

Comment: also a lot more convenient if what you want to print is of mixed types

Comment: It can make localization a lot easier as word order can change between languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, try doing this with `+`:

```
>>> concatenate_me = (1,2,99999,100,600, 80)
>>>'{0} {0} {2} {2} {1} {2} {3} {5} {5} {4} {0} {2}'.format(*concatenate_me)
```

**`.format()` benefits:**

- Contains *placeholders*, <sup>*i.e.*</sup>`..{0}..{1}..{2}`. Using `.format`, arguments passed are substituted into their respective placeholders (based on their order). This allows you to re-use arguments, as seen in the example above.
- In each replacement with `.format`, you have a [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (`:`). This specification allows you control with respect to many properties for each substitution you make, and there's a whole mini-language for it.

Additionally, `.format` is a function, which you can pass as an argument when needed. In Python 3 it is called [advanced string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) as it is much more powerful than simple concatenation.

---

You can do some pretty wild and flexible things if you *really* want using the `.format` function as well, for instance:

```
>>>'Python {0.version_info[0]:!<13.2%}'.format(sys)
'Python 300.00%!!!!!!'
```

And one further example with a dictionary, to display its ability to take keyword arguments:

```
>>>my_dict = { 'adjective': 'cool', 'function':'format'}
>>>"Look how awesome my {adjective} Python {function} skills are!".format(**my_dict)
'Look how awesome my cool Python format skills are.'
```

There's some further examples and uses in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 1):

`format` is much more powerful, and as you can see in the other answer, you can do a loot of cool things with it. However, I would like to add that format is not the fastest (at least in python 3.4 on ubuntu 14.04). For simple formatting, plus notation is faster. For example:

```
import timeit


print(timeit.timeit("name = \"Doe\"; surname = \"John\"; 'He is {0} {1}'.format(surname, name)", number=100000))
# 0.04642631400201935

print(timeit.timeit("name = \"Doe\"; surname = \"John\"; \"He is\" + surname + \" \" + name", number=100000))
# 0.01718082799925469
```